# AllowEditRanges.Add troubles

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with AllowEditRanges. The following code is correct for a range from a1 to g1:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
ws.Unprotect
ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Classified", Range:=Range("A1:G1"), Password:="pw"
ws.Protect
```

The second I change the range into `Range:=Range("$A:$G;$I:$O")` I get the following error:

Error 1004: Method Range object _global failed  (sorry for the translation)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: VBA always uses a comma (`,`) as the delimiter - regardless of regional variation. replace your semi-colon (`;`) with a comma instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a comma in like this:

```
Range("$A:$G,$I:$O")
```